# Is it possible to compute the logical AND and OR with logistic regression?

Tags: function-approximation, logistic-regression

It's easy to build a perceptron that can compute the [logical AND and OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations) functions of its binary inputs.

Logistic regression could be used as a binary classifier.

$$z^{(i)} = w^T x^{(i)} + b$$

$$\hat{y}^{(i)} = a^{(i)} = sigmoid(z^{(i)})$$

$$
\sigma(z) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}
$$

Is it possible to compute the AND and OR with [logistic regression](https://youtu.be/z_xiwjEdAC4?list=PLkDaE6sCZn6Ec-XTbcX1uRg2_u4xOEky0&t=44)?